# How to animate a shape to expand/morph a certain way?

Tags: after-effects

I am trying to animate a square into a an isometric cube-like shape. In the image, I want the square on the left to "extrude" into the cube on the right. How can I achieve this effect? [image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I merge two shapes in one during an animation?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/35663/how-do-i-merge-two-shapes-in-one-during-an-animation)

Comment: See https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/35663/how-do-i-merge-two-shapes-in-one-during-an-animation/35672#35672